# Error while installing quick.db in discord.js

Tags: node.js, npm, quick.db

This is my [error](https://pastebin.com/4t48LPhj). I constantly keep getting this error while trying to `npm install quick.db`

I am using Visual Studio Code, Node version 17.0.0, discord.js version 13.3.1, please help me, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See the installation section of **[quick.db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db#installation)**

[image]

## Troubleshooting quick.db/better-sqlite3 installation

1. Make sure you're using nodejs v10.20.1 or later
2. Make sure you have [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) globally installed, including all of [its dependencies](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-unix). On Windows you may need to [configure some things manually](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows). Use `npm ls node-gyp` to make sure none of your local packages installed an outdated version of `node-gyp` that is used over the global one.
3. If you're using [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron), try running [`electron-rebuild`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-rebuild)
4. If you're using Windows, follow these steps. Do them **in this order**, and **don't skip steps**.

   1. Install the **latest** of node 10, 12, or 14.
   2. Install **latest** Visual Studio Community and Desktop Development with C++ extension.
   3. Install **latest** Python.
   4. Run following commands:

   ```
   npm config set msvs_version 2019
   npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
   ```

   5. Run `npm install quick.db`